# How to find rtmp streaming url from flashvars (decode)?

Tags: javascript, url, streaming

I am attempting to find the rtmp stream for the video on this page: http://www.livenewschat.eu/canada/

I have attempted Media Sniffer, Web Sniffer, Download Helper, Chrome's Developer Tools (and looking at the Network Traffic) and I can't find the url. The closest I have come is using Chrome's Developer Tools, and finding the flashvars parameter:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="netstreambasepath=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livenewschat.eu%2Fcanada%2F&amp;id=6fe82a5201dec175e746dcba7605dd4d&amp;skin=http%3A%2F%2Fnewschat.tv%2Ftheme.zip&amp;author=livenewschat.eu&amp;stretching=uniform&amp;file=cbc_live&amp;image=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livenewschat.eu%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F05%2Fnews-banner-640.jpg&amp;autostart=true&amp;streamer=rtmp%3A%2F%2Fdiljon.cdn.newschat.tv%2Fedge&amp;controlbar.position=bottom">
```

I also found the javascript for it as well:

```
function serverReady(data)
{
    jQuery("div#6fe82a5201dec175e746dcba7605dd4d").html = '<a href="//www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="//www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a>';
    var playerVars = 
    {
        skin: "http://newschat.tv/theme.zip",
        flashplayer: "http://newschat.tv/player.swf",
        author: "livenewschat.eu",
        stretching: "uniform",
        file: "cbc_live",
        image: "http://www.livenewschat.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/news-banner-640.jpg",
        autostart: "true",
        controlbar: "bottom",
        width: 640,
        height: 385 
    };
    playerVars["streamer"] = "rtmp://" + data.best + "/edge";
    if (playerVars["plugins"] !== undefined)
    {
        playerVars["plugins"]["streamer"] = playerVars["streamer"];
    }
    jwplayer("6fe82a5201dec175e746dcba7605dd4d").setup(playerVars);
};
```

So it would SEEM that my rtmp stream is rtmp://diljon.cdn.newschat.tv/edge/cbc_live

But, NO. It's not. You know what's playing? HE MAN!!! He's singing "What's Going On?" Had to double check and make sure I wasn't having a flashback or something LOL. What am I doing wrong? How can I find the stream? I want to use it in Kodi.

Answer (score 0):

The url currently is:

URL=rtmp://howdy.cdn.newschat.tv/edge playpath=msnbc_live swfUrl=http://pro.livenewschat.tv/player.swf swfVfy=1 live=1 pageUrl=http://www.livenewschat.eu/politics/ timeout=15

You need to view source and find the server url:

src="http://newschat.tv/server.json"

Then put that in the browser and it will reveal:

serverReady({"totalConns":412,"best":"howdy.cdn.newschat.tv"});

the url after "best" is what you want to add between rtmp:// and  /edge